# Google Docs Spreadsheet form entry add record

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Docs sheet that is primarily maintained by form.  I have several functions that act on this & another sheet within the same spreadsheet.  I would like to have one of my functions add a record to the same sheet that the form is typically entered on, but need each of these rows to maintain their position in the sheet.

I have noticed that when I add the record thru the script at the bottom of the sheet & then another record is added thru the form that my script records are moved down to the next row of the spreadsheet.  What can I do to prevent this (cause the form to place the next record at the bottom not just underneath the last form entered record)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you require the "script-added" record to be absorbed into the form responses, which is defined by the light grey area. I provided a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569224/google-apps-script-appendrow-doesnt-increase-form-record-count) which simply involves copying the last row "in place" after it has been added, which causes it to be absorbed into the light grey area (as long as it is immediately adjacent to it).

So, say you have a variable `range` that you use to set your values at the end of the script, then use something like this:

```
range.setValues(values);
range.copyTo(range);
```